# ASP.Net Page Content with Scrollbars

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a nice design for a webpage and in the middle is a contentplaceholder. Now I want that, if the content is longer then the height in the div, it should be have his own scroll bars, like IFrames.

How to realize?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of a div with scroll bars. Put a div like that inside your content place holder :

```
<div style="height:100px;width:100px;overflow:scroll;">
    Your content here.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
#content
{
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
</style>
<div id="content">
</div>
```

This code would show only the horizontal scrollbar, you want both of then, just remove the overflow-y line.